# SearchView losing focus on the TextField

Tags: android, searchview

So i have this `SearchView` inside a sliding drawer menu. The problem is when i tap the `SearchView` for the first time, it wont let me type anything, i need to tap on it again the second time before it works. This is the first time i encountered this problem hope anyone will help me. Thanks.

First Tap (not working!):

[image]

Second Tap (working) :

[image]

And here are my codes :

```
SearchView search = null;

search = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
search.setQueryHint("Search Picklrs");
search.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color = #b3b3b3>" + "Search Picklrs" + "</font>"));
int id = search.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);

search.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            Intent i = new Intent(context, SearchResultsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", query);
            context.startActivity(i);

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {return false;}
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

Use `search.setFocusable(true);` for that `SearchView`

```
search = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
search.setFocusable(true);
search.performClick();
search.requestFocus();
search.setIconified(true);
```

Comment: i tried the edited answer, thank you but it doesn't work either :( Thank you though. Ill give an upvote.

Comment: Maybe there's just something that conflicts with my program. Ill try to find it.

Comment: @GreenFox can you remove `search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);` this try.